# How to extract only links finished by extensions .swf from the source code of a web page?

Tags: powershell, flash

I wonder how to extract only links finished by extensions .swf from the source code of a web page and save them on text file in order to download them after ?

So i just have this code :

```
$ie = new-object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate2('http://www.addictinggames.com/car-games/moto-x3m-game.jsp')
while($ie.Busy){}
$ie.Document.links|select href
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `|Select -Expand href | Where{$_ -like "*.swf"}`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician no i get nothing because,i think what i want to catch is http://www.addictinggames.com/newGames/car-games/moto-x3m/moto-x3m.swf and is located under a javascript not a link ? so is there a workaround to do that correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$wc = New-Object net.webclient
$data = $wc.DownloadString('http://www.addictinggames.com/car-games/moto-x3m-game.jsp')
$rx = [regex]::Escape("com.mtvnet.games.GameSettings.Game.metadata.gameURL") + '\s*=\s*[\x27\x22]([^?]+)'
$link = [regex]::Match($data,$rx).groups[1].value
$link
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
$ie.Document.body.innerHTML  |out-file c:\temp\source.html
$source =gc C:\temp\source.html
($source |Select-String "(\<(.)*\.swf)"  -AllMatches)[3]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i got nothing ? what should i do now ?